# foreign key constraint not letting delete row from table in django

Tags: mysql, django

I create below model in Django.

```
class ClientsModel(models.Model):
    sys_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False, blank=True)
    tenant_sys_id = models.ForeignKey('tenant.TenantModel', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
    # and few more rows.
```

Here tenant_sys_id is a foreign key. I set on_delete = models.SET_NULL, which means if I delete any entry from TenantModel (lets say entry1) then column tenant_sys_id in all rows having tenant_sys_id as entry1 should be set to null. I am right here?
If yes- Then here is next question. If I try to delete an entry from tenants table from mysql then it is throwing me below error.

```
mysql> delete from tenants where sys_id = 1;
ERROR 1451 (23000): Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sanstha_db`.`clients`, CONSTRAINT `Clients_tenant_sys_id_id_52191b87_fk_Tenants_sys_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_sys_id_id`) REFERENCES `tenants` (`sys_id`))
```

Here is the table structure.

```
Table: clients
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `clients` (
  `sys_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `last_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(140) NOT NULL,
  `is_business` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_vendor` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `is_authorized_to_expense` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `relation` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dob` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `gender` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_when` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_when` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_by` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `notes` varchar(2048) DEFAULT NULL,
  `head_of_family_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_sys_id_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sys_id`),
  KEY `Clients_head_of_family_id_01c17980_fk_Clients_sys_id` (`head_of_family_id`),
  KEY `Clients_tenant_sys_id_id_52191b87_fk_Tenants_sys_id` (`tenant_sys_id_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Clients_head_of_family_id_01c17980_fk_Clients_sys_id` FOREIGN KEY (`head_of_family_id`) REFERENCES `clients` (`sys_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Clients_tenant_sys_id_id_52191b87_fk_Tenants_sys_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tenant_sys_id_id`) REFERENCES `tenants` (`sys_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Please suggest me why it is not letting me delete the entry? what is the correct way to do it.

Comment: It says that you have problem with `clients` table, not `users`

Comment: oh...sorry...updated question.

Comment: The model you've shown has `tenant_sys_id` as the `foreign key`. And you are saying that `parent_sys_id` is a `foreign key`. So are there more `Models` or have you mistakenly written `tenant_sys_id` as `parent_sys_id`. Coz the above is not really making sense to me. Can you explain the scenario with a better example, if there is no mistake in what you have written above?

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi - updated the question...there was a mistake..earlier I used another model.

Comment: Are you making that **raw sql query** in your `views` or are you making that query in another terminal by using **mysql** command line. Coz if its the former case, then I know the issue.

Comment: @AnkushRaghuvanshi - from terminal...Anyways let me know the first case solution as well, just in case.

Answer (score 4):

So here's the catch.

`on_delete = models.SET_NULL` will replace the value of that `foreign key` (which you deleted in the parent table) with `null` value.

But the above will be done by **Django** when say you write some logic in your `views.py` to delete some row of `tenants` models, as the `on_delete = Models.SET_NULL` is something defined in **Django** and not in **MySQL**.

So when you do that in your `views.py`, then Django interprets it, then makes the foreign keys null in the model `ClientsModel` and ONLY after that it deletes the row from the model `tenants`.

But if you do that from the another terminal by using the **MySQL** command line, then you are not interacting with Django and directly deleting the row from the table `tenants`. This way, the foreign keys in the model `ClientsModel` won't be set to **null** and hence you'll get the `foreign key constraint error`

And lastly, the answer to your last comment. You won't get this error if you delete a row from Django, irrespective of whether you use Django's ORM or raw SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks...got it...But these tables are created by django right... so why django didn't created tables in such way that we can handle this situation form terminal also...

Comment: Django is just a framework. MySQL and Django are independent of each other. You can use any other backend framework to do the same and use MySQL as you database. Framework is a layer where you right your logic of how your frontend interacts with your database. So Django has some in-built features which **write** to the database in a particular way, but can't change the characteristic properties of how a Database behaves, be it MySQL, PostgreSQL or Mongo.

Comment: If you'll use `python manage.py shell` to delete the rows, then it will definitely be handled and you won't get the error as now you are interacting with your Database **via** Django. But obviously you'll get the error if you'll use `mysql -u root -p` in another terminal and directly delete a row without letting Django knowing it.